# When is one exempt from liability when performing a mitzvah

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, torts-damages, bava-kamma

In the Talmud in [tractate Bava Kamma 62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.62b) a store owner isn’t liable for placing a Hanukkah candle outside, even if it Causes damage to a camel. My question is, does this principle of exemption from liability because of performance of a mitzvah apply to other mitzvot, or just Hanukkah candles? Related [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34308/circumcision-liability) about Brit milah.

Comment: I thought that heter was because the rabbis allowed you to place it there. But one can't extrapolate to other places.

Comment: This relates to this question - https://www.etzion.org.il/he/talmud/seder-nezikin/massekhet-bava-kamma/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA

Comment: Note that this is only according to R. Yehudah's opinion there. The Sages (whom the halachah follows) don't exempt him, since even though he's supposed to put the candle out there, he's also expected to watch it to make sure it doesn't cause damage.